# Warning 1265 for date_added,date_modified column In MySQL During Calling Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

I HAVE TABLE

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product_universal_description`;

CREATE TABLE `product_universal_description` (
  `pud_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `upc_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `model_no` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` INT(11),
  `return_id` INT(11),
  `damage_id` INT(11),
  `condition_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `status_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `added_by` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` INT NOT NULL,
  `date_added` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`pud_id`)
);

ALTER TABLE product_universal_description ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`upc_id`),ADD INDEX (`product_id`),ADD INDEX (`supplier_id`),ADD INDEX (`warehouse_id`),ADD INDEX (`order_id`),ADD INDEX (`return_id`),ADD INDEX (`damage_id`);
```

FOR This I have made one procedure to add record.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addRecordOnPUD;

CREATE PROCEDURE addRecordOnPUD
( 
  IN qty int(4), 
  IN upc varchar(32), 
  IN product_id int(11), 
  IN supplier_id int(11), 
  IN location_id varchar(32), 
  IN model_no varchar(64), 
  IN warehouse_id int(11),
  IN user_id int(11),
  IN date_added datetime,
  IN date_modified datetime,
  OUT message VARCHAR(64)
)

BEGIN 

  DECLARE temp_upc VARCHAR(32);
  DECLARE i INT;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062 
  SET message = CONCAT('DUPLICATE KEYS ',upc,' FOUND');
  SET i = 1;

  WHILE qty > 0 DO

    SET temp_upc = CONCAT(upc,'-',i);

    INSERT INTO product_universal_description
      (
        `upc_id`,
        `product_id`,
        `supplier_id`,
        `location_id`,
        `model_no`,
        `warehouse_id`,
        `added_by`,
        `updated_by`,
        `date_added`,
        `date_modified`
        ) VALUES (
        temp_upc,
        product_id,
        supplier_id,
        location_id,
        model_no,
        warehouse_id,
        user_id,
        user_id,
        date_added,
        date_modified
      );

    SET i=i+1;
    SET qty=qty-1;

  END WHILE;
  IF message IS NULL THEN
    SET message = 'successfully added';
  END IF;
END;
```

While calling the procedure

```
CALL addRecordOnPUD(8, 'po', 44, '44', 44, 'cfb', 44, 44,NOW(),NOW(),@message);
```

I am getting that

```
1265: Data truncated for column 'date_added' at row 1
1265: Data truncated for column 'date_modified' at row 1
```

What could be the proper solution for this ? I searched But I got the solution related to INT where the data was exceed the limit. Please Help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you prepend your parameter names with a consistent prefix to distinguish them from the column names. Otherwise when you reference a name like `date_added` it is ambiguous whether you are referencing the column name or the parameter name.

Here's an example modifying your procedure to use a `p_` prefix for the parameter names. Give it a try and see if this solves your problem:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addRecordOnPUD $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addRecordOnPUD
( 
  IN p_qty int(4), 
  IN p_upc varchar(32), 
  IN p_product_id int(11), 
  IN p_supplier_id int(11), 
  IN p_location_id varchar(32), 
  IN p_model_no varchar(64), 
  IN p_warehouse_id int(11),
  IN p_user_id int(11),
  IN p_date_added datetime,
  IN p_date_modified datetime,
  OUT p_message VARCHAR(64)
)

BEGIN 

  DECLARE v_temp_upc VARCHAR(32);
  DECLARE i INT;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062 
  SET p_message = CONCAT('DUPLICATE KEYS ',p_upc,' FOUND');
  SET i = 1;

  WHILE p_qty > 0 DO

    SET v_temp_upc = CONCAT(p_upc,'-',i);

    INSERT INTO product_universal_description
      (
        `upc_id`,
        `product_id`,
        `supplier_id`,
        `location_id`,
        `model_no`,
        `warehouse_id`,
        `added_by`,
        `updated_by`,
        `date_added`,
        `date_modified`
        ) VALUES (
        v_temp_upc,
        p_product_id,
        p_supplier_id,
        p_location_id,
        p_model_no,
        p_warehouse_id,
        p_user_id,
        p_user_id,
        p_date_added,
        p_date_modified
      );

    SET i=i+1;
    SET p_qty=p_qty-1;

  END WHILE;
  IF p_message IS NULL THEN
    SET p_message = 'successfully added';
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```